# Display order customer note in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I am trying to get the customers additional order message:

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to display that customer message on the email notifications.
But i don't know how to get this information in the php code.

Here is my code in the functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'ts_email_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
function ts_email_after_order_table( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text){
    $notes=$order->customer_message; //did not work
    echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; color: #636363; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;" border="0"><tbody><tr><td><p>Test: ' . $notes . '</p></td></tr></tbody></table>';
}
```

I really don't know how to access that information.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. Using the `WC_Order` method [get_customer_note()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_customer_note), try the following instead, that will display for some successful email notifications, the customer order note:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'customer_note_email_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
function customer_note_email_after_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // Only on some email notifications
    if ( in_array( $email->id, array('new_order', 'customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order') ) ) :

    // Get customer Order note
    $customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();

    // Display the Customer order notes section
    echo '<h2>' . __("Order notes", "woocommerce") . '</h2>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; color: #636363; border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;" border="0">
        <tr><td><p>' . $customer_note . '</p></td></tr>
    </table></div>';

    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you very much!