# Add order customer note to YITH Woocommerce PDF Invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, invoice

In Woocommerce I am using a plugin called [YITH WooCommerce PDF Invoice and Shipping List](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-pdf-invoice/) and I would like to add customer note to the PDF invoice.

I would like to add it after the first span line in the code below:

```
        <span class="notes-title"><?php _e( "Notes", "yith-woocommerce-pdf-invoice" ); ?></span>    
        <div class="notes">
            <span><?php echo nl2br( $notes ); ?></span>
            <?php do_action( 'yith_ywpi_after_document_notes', $document );?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
```

But i can't figure out how to get the customer note from `$document` variable.

I have tried to use this answer thread: "[Display Customer order comments (customer note) in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144737/display-customer-order-comments-customer-note-in-woocommerce/27149457#27149457)" which looks pretty much like the same problem but still could'nt figure it out as `$document->order->customer_message;` doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 you can't access anymore properties From the `WC_Order` object. You need to use the `WC_Order` method [`get_customer_note()`][1].

So from the `$document` (YITH global object) you will use:

```
$document->order->get_customer_note();
```

**To add customer notes to YITH invoice you can choose between 2 ways:**

1) Using the available `yith_ywpi_after_document_notes` **action hook**:

```
add_action( 'yith_ywpi_invoice_template_products_list', 'add_customer_notes_after_document_notes', 5 );
function add_customer_notes_after_document_notes( $document ) {
    ?><span><?php echo $document->order->get_customer_note(); ?></span><?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Untested *(as I dont have the premium version of the plugin)* but it should work normally *(depending on the plugin settings)*.

2) Overriding templates (in your provided code):

```
    <span class="notes-title"><?php _e( "Notes", "yith-woocommerce-pdf-invoice" ); ?></span>    
    <div class="notes">
        <span><?php echo nl2br( $notes ); ?></span>
        <span><?php echo $document->order->get_customer_note(); ?></span>
        <?php do_action( 'yith_ywpi_after_document_notes', $document );?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
```

It should work.

---

> **For the free plugin version**

- There is no available hooks (like in the provided code)…
- The YITH PDF global object **need to be called** and it's not `$document`.

So you will be able to use the following code in `templates/invoice/invoice-footer.php` template:

```
 <?php global $ywpi_document; echo $ywpi_document->order->get_customer_note(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was super helpful and worked perfectly.. :)